# What is the most appropriate clock/time source for software-based signal processing?

Tags: raspberry-pi, signal-processing, software-defined-radio

Let's say I want to sample a pair of GPIO pins of my Raspberry Pi* with a frequency around 10kHz to feed a software-based signal analyzer (written in C for instance). What is the most appropriate method to obtain an accurate timestamp for each sample? Accurate means, the delay between acqiring the sample and reading the clock/time source should be at least constant or negligible at best. The signal analyzer does not necessarily operate in realtime.

I am aware that the sampling quality may also be affected by other circumstances (e.g. preemptive mulititasking), but the question is only about acuqiring an accurate timestamp for each sample.

*) In general: any signal like a pulse wave (high/low) or an audio signal (quantized). The Raspberry Pi is only an example, since it has everything to acquire the signal already built-in.

Comment: You want to sample what RaspberryPi outputs or want to write code for RaspberryPi which processes the inputs? Consider tagging RaspberryPi.

Comment: Unless you're running a hard real time operating system sampling things in software is probably a bad idea. In general these kinds of applications usually either do sampling in hardware to a buffer which then a driver reads periodically or the samples have timestamps provided by the hardware. Also, if you're reading from userland (not a driver in the kernel) you might have problems getting a frequency better than 100Hz.

Comment: Question as written has nothing really to do with C, unless you are asking about how to use the C libraries to produce time-stamps. Then you would want to include some code, showing the attempt of what you have tried. And as already commented, you should include `Raspberry Pi` tag.  For starters, _[what reading have you done](http://www.hertaville.com/introduction-to-accessing-the-raspberry-pis-gpio-in-c.html)_?

Comment: The raspberry is only an example to acquire the source signalr. The method may or may not be platform dependent. I consider this part of the answer. In the same manner, C is a likely candidate for such a piece of software, but maybe assembler would be a better choice.

Comment: Is this article  in the ballpark of what you want to do? _[Introduction to accessing the Raspberry Pi's GPIO in C++ (sysfs)](http://www.hertaville.com/introduction-to-accessing-the-raspberry-pis-gpio-in-c.html)_?  From there, you could easily enough add code to use C libraries to log time-stamps.

Comment: @Art Thank you. That's the kind of insight I am interested in.

Comment: @ryyker Yes, basically, but my question is about the sampling accurary, not the mere "read the value from a GPIO pin" part.

Comment: _["Firstly, timing done via software loops involves endless fussing over the exact clock cycle count. This code solves that problem by using..."](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52393)_.  Maybe this will address some of your questions.

Comment: How long do you need to acquire for - total duration?